# Parse a .txt file for a keyword then looking for sub-keywords?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies for the title, I don't really know how to word this question correctly.

I have a script that pulls configuration from Cisco switches saving to a .txt file and I want to extract key information. Below is an extract of what is in the extracted .txt file:

```
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel10
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description ** Uplink to C1 **
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 95
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description ** Uplink to C2 **
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 95
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
 channel-group 10 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description ** Downlink to NetAuto **
  switchport access vlan 95
  switchport mode access
  media-type rj45
  negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
 channel-group 10 mode auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 media-type rj45
```

I'm hoping to extract the following information from the above .txt file:

- interface info (for all)
- description (if it exists)
- channel-group number (if it exists)

An example output of what im hoping for is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description ** Uplink to C1 **
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description ** Uplink to C2 **
 channel-group 10
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description ** Downlink to NetAuto **
```

and so on...

Below is my current code however, its not giving me anywhere near what I want it to and i'm all out of ideas with my limited python knowledge:

```
with open('newfile1', 'r') as fi:
    int = []
    desc = []
    for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("interface"):
            int = (ln)
            print(int) 
            for ln in fi: 
                if ln.startswith(" description"): 
                    desc = (ln) 
                    print(desc)
```

This returns:

```
interface Port-channel10

 description ** Uplink to C1 **

 description ** Uplink to C2 **

 description ** Downlink to NetAuto **
```

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong with the results of your code--your description is extremely vague. Please remind yourself of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow it.

Comment: Do you want them stored in separate lists or just a single list?

Comment: Separate lists ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to structure the data well for use. I would suggest that you use a dictionary to store the details of each interface. So, the data extracted from the file would be a list of such dictionaries. The code for the same would look something like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('interface'):
            data.append(dict(interface=line.replace('interface', '').strip()))
            print(line) # check it on the console

        if line.strip().startswith('description'):
            data[-1]['description'] = line.replace('description', '').strip()
            print(line) # check it on the console

        if line.strip().startswith('channel-group'):
            data[-1]['channel-group'] = line.replace('channel-group', '').strip()
            print(line) # check it on the console

print(data) # prints a list of dicts
```

The data will be:

```
[{'interface': 'Port-channel10'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/0', 'description': '** Uplink to C1 **'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/1', 'description': '** Uplink to C2 **', 'channel-group': '10 mode auto'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/2', 'description': '** Downlink to NetAuto **'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/3', 'channel-group': '10 mode auto'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet1/0'}, {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet1/1'}]
```

Comment: This is the solution I needed. Thanks a bunch Vignesh!

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
result = []
with open(filename) as infile:    #Filename == Your File 
    for line in infile:           #Iterate Each line
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("interface GigabitEthernet"):   #Check condition
            result.append([line])
            while True:
                try:
                    line = next(infile).strip()
                except:  #Handle StopIteration Error
                    break
                if line == "!":
                    break
                if line.startswith("description"):   #Check condition
                    result[-1].append(line)
                if line.startswith("channel-group"):   #Check condition
                    result[-1].append(line)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['interface GigabitEthernet0/0', 'description ** Uplink to C1 **'],
 ['interface GigabitEthernet0/1',
  'description ** Uplink to C2 **',
  'channel-group 10 mode auto'],
 ['interface GigabitEthernet0/2', 'description ** Downlink to NetAuto **'],
 ['interface GigabitEthernet0/3', 'channel-group 10 mode auto'],
 ['interface GigabitEthernet1/0'],
 ['interface GigabitEthernet1/1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple - split the text file into lines, split the line into words, check the first word is in the list of words you are interested in.

```
results = []
first_words = ['interface', 'description', 'channel-group']
input_file = 'switch.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as switch_file:
    for line in switch_file.readlines():
        words_in_line = line.split()
        # There should be at least 1 word in the line
        if 0 < len(words_in_line):
            first_word = words_in_line[0]
            if any(first_word in s for s in first_words):
                results.append(line.rstrip())

print("\n".join(results))
```

Output:

```
interface Port-channel10
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description ** Uplink to C1 **
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description ** Uplink to C2 **
 channel-group 10 mode auto
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description ** Downlink to NetAuto **
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 channel-group 10 mode auto
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
```

Comment: I get an error: print(words_in_line[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Perhaps there are empty lines in your file, in which case `words_in_line` will be empty. I'll update the answer to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
first_words = {'interface', 'description', 'channel-group'}

res = []
with open('input.txt') as input_f:
    d = []
    first = True
    for i in filter(lambda l: l.strip().split(' ')[0] in {'interface', 'description', 'channel-group'}, input_f):
        if 'interface' in i:
            first = False if first else res.append(d)
            d = []
        d.append(i.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The good way to do

You could achieve that with a few lines of code, this solution has been detailed is other solutions, but what you need in fact is to [build a Parser](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/#tools): it would be definitely cleaner and sustainable.

You could find more information there:

- http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/65/how-to-build-a-parser-by-hand
- http://zderadicka.eu/writing-simple-parser-in-python/

#### The workaround

If what you need is just a quick workaround, you can do like that:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^(interface)|(description).*')

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f, open('result.txt', 'w+') as rf:
    result = [l for l in f if rx.match(l.strip())]
    rf.write(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Will look into this some more. Thanks olinox14